# Android app settings not showing up

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android app and I want to give the user a few settings that they can customize. However, whenever I go to press the Settings button in the overflow, it does not load the settings and my app crashes.

Here is my menu and menu switcher code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is the setting activty:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Here is the preferences fragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Is there another way I am supposed to handle the settings page? I followed the instructions from the Android Developer site.

On a quick side note, how do I store those settings and access them in the main activity?

Comment: If your App crashes, it will report the stack trace in LogCat. Run adb logcat from a terminal and trace through the messages to see where the App failed. If you're still having issues, post the logcat output in your question.

Comment: for your SideNode: have a look at SharedPreferences or other http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html data-storage options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you remember to put SettingsActivity in your manifest?

Comment: This should be a comment, especially if you aren't going to elaborate on it

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include this in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="Settings"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```